# How to intercept submitted form data (MasaCMS)

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I would like to ask you if there is any way to intercept submitted form data similar to [mura contacts](https://github.com/stevewithington/muracontacts)  as `$.event('formfield')` does not seem to work for me (returns null).

I get only values for url variables via `$.event('urlvariable')` and not for form variables. More information [here](https://github.com/MasaCMS/MasaCMS/discussions/256).

Regards

Comment: Did you check the `form` scope? [cfdocs form scope](https://cfdocs.org/scopes#form-scope)  Try adding `<cfdump var="#form#">` to your output page. That should show you the form scope contents.

Comment: Ensure that the actual form tag includes `method="post"`.

Comment: All checks have been done. But remains the same problem. For more information  https://github.com/MasaCMS/MasaCMS/discussions/256